# Allow column resize in jqgrid when access over remote desktop

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a web application that use the jqGrid component. When I access the page in a browser running locally, I can use the mouse to adjust the width of the columns (jqgrid default functionality). But when the same site is access in the same browser version running over remote desktop, the columns are locked and the width cannot be changed.

How can I make the columns adjustable also when running over remote desktop?

jqgrid version 4.4.1

Comment: what kind of remote access program you use? It could be the problem of the remote access program because in general all should work **exactly** as locally.

Comment: This is RDP, but I realised I'd only connected using freerdp. With MS' RDP client it does work as expected. I reported a bug for that: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/1637?source=c